# Refresh a view on TabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have a TabBarController, with three views, one of which is the settings view. When I go to the settings page, then come out of the app and go back in, I need the view to refresh. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to refresh, and what your setting looks like?

If your setting view has a **done** or **save** button, you can put the refresh code there, `[someController.theTable reloadData]` for example.

Another way is to put the refresh code inside `viewWillAppear:` in the view that you want to refresh, info can be found here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIViewController